# how to update a row in db in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I have a table & need to add a comments column in the table where comments could be updated when the user types in the text box and click submit. I have tried the code below but cant understands why it does not function correctly. I've done a lot of research over this but hit a roadblock after road block, so I really hope your help in this, many thanks!

```
<form method="post" action="tea_appview.php">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-condensed" id="example">
<!--      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-bordered" id="example">  -->
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>appoinment ID</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>time</th>
            <th>subject</th>
            <th>Appointment from [parent]</th>
            <th>Appointment to (teacher) </th>
            <th> accept/reject </th>
            <th>state</th>
            <th>comm</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from `app` left join `par` on par.par_id=app.par_id left join `tea` on tea.tea_id=app.tea_id ORDER BY app_id DESC");
        if ($query === false) {
            throw new Exception(mysqli_error($conn));
        }
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $ann_id = $row['app_id'];
            $date = $row['date'];
            $msg = $row['time'];
            $username = $row['username'];
            $username = $row['p_username'];
            $sub = $row['sub'];
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['app_id'] ?></td>
            <td> <?php echo date('j/m/y', strtotime($row['date'])); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['time'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['sub'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['p_username'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['username'] ?></td>
            <td>
                <a href="tea_appview.php?app_id=<?php echo $row['app_id'] . "&" . "state=reject"; ?>" class="reject">reject</a>
                <a href="tea_appview.php?app_id=<?php echo $row['app_id'] . "&" . "state=accept"; ?>" class="accept">accept</a> 
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $row['state'] ?></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="comm">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
            //---------PROBLEM IS HERE-----------------------
            //if(isset($_GET['app_id'], $_POST['submit'])!="")
            if (isset($_GET['app_id']) && $_POST['submit'] != ""){
                $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "UPDATE app SET comm = ? WHERE app_id = ?");
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sd", $_GET['comm'], $_GET['app_id']);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();
            }
            //-------------------------------
            if (isset($_GET['state'], $_GET['app_id'])) {
                $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "UPDATE app SET state = ? WHERE app_id = ?");
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sd", $_GET['state'], $_GET['app_id']);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();
            }
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Look how to do this using ajax imho

Comment: @LilianBarraud i did the exact same thing for "STATE" it works but when i try to add a textbox  something is wrong

Comment: `$_GET['app_id']` doesn't seem to be passed to the script in POST. Hence, `if (isset($_GET['app_id']) && $_POST['submit'] != "") {`
 fails

Comment: @KarloKokkak what do u want me to do

Comment: Do you also update comm column?

Comment: What is data type of column app_id? Is it INT?

Comment: @KarloKokkak thats what i need to do

Comment: @KarloKokkak app_id is int

Answer (score -1):

While loop scope is reduced to just include outputing of data in table. While, previously included in the while loop, database update block is now moved to the very top so that updates will already show in the table output below.

Also updated the conditions in the if statements.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['app_id']) && $_POST['app_id'] != "" && isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "UPDATE app SET comm = ? WHERE app_id = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "si", $_POST['comm'], $_POST['app_id']);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
//-------------------------------
if (isset($_GET['state'], $_GET['app_id'])) {
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "UPDATE app SET state = ? WHERE app_id = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "si", $_GET['state'], $_GET['app_id']);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

?>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-condensed" id="example">
     <!--      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-bordered" id="example">  -->
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>appoinment ID</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>time</th>
            <th>subject</th>
            <th>Appointment from [parent]</th>
            <th>Appointment to (teacher) </th>
            <th> accept/reject </th>
            <th>state</th>
            <th>comm</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from `app` left join `par` on par.par_id=app.par_id
                    left join `tea` on tea.tea_id=app.tea_id
                    ORDER BY app_id DESC");

        if ($query === false) {
            throw new Exception(mysqli_error($conn));
        }
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $ann_id = $row['app_id'];
            $date = $row['date'];
            $msg = $row['time'];

            $username = $row['username'];
            $username = $row['p_username'];
            $sub = $row['sub'];
            ?>
            <form method="post" action="tea_appview.php">  
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['app_id'] ?></td>
                <td> <?php echo date('j/m/y', strtotime($row['date'])); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['time'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['sub'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['p_username'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['username'] ?></td>

                <td>
                    <a href="tea_appview.php?app_id=<?php echo $row['app_id'] . "&" . "state=reject"; ?>" class="reject">reject</a>
                    <a href="tea_appview.php?app_id=<?php echo $row['app_id'] . "&" . "state=accept"; ?>" class="accept">accept</a> 
                </td>
                <td><?php echo $row['state'] ?></td>


                <td><input type="text" name="comm" value="<?php echo $row['comm']; ?>"><input type="hidden" name="app_id" value="<?php echo $row['app_id']; ?>">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
                </td>  
            </tr>
            </form>

<?php } ?>



    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can u pls tell what have u changed here

Comment: it is worse than earlier...i think u missed the form action

Comment: The form action is there.

Comment: it does not throw any errors but the text box does not get submit **what happened earlier was when i press submit the text in text box get cleared but the db not updated now it does not even get cleared**

Comment: i just saw the form action

Comment: You need enclose with `<form></form>` each app record so the script knows which app to update with the comment. As it is now with the update.

Comment: Btw, does the script connect to the database successfully somewhere in your code?

Comment: yeah in the accept/reject spot the db works perfectly fine